# Insert error with dapper dot net Cannot update identity column

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, orm, sql-update, dapper

I'm new add dapper dot net so do forgive me if this question is quite easy for you.

I have my object wich I would like to save to te database. But when I execute my update command I get an error saying that I cannot update the identy column.

I'm not aloud to make any changes to the properties of my sql database, I'm using dapper extension and my project is written in vb.net.

How can I save my object?

Comment: you can't update identity column. Instead based on your identity column you can update other column values.

Comment: I understand this but my question is how to do this by code?
my object is cursus and i update it to de db as followed:
     _conn.Update(cursus)

Comment: why do you need to update the identity column in the first place?

Comment: I wish not to update the identity column, but it is present in my object, so when i excute the update command it is in being updated with the same value.

Answer (score 0):

A little old post but I was experiencing same problem. In my case I solved the problem creating a POCO class without the Identity column .

My entity  is:

```
public class MyEntity
{
    public decimal Id {get;set;} // Marked at SQL Db as Identity
    other properties 
}
```

To work with dapper-extensions `Insert` just remove Identity column at your POCO class

```
public class MyEntity
{
    other properties 
}
```

As you said you can't change the database, but at your code you could create your own poco's.